# for a newbie,what is the best web app to develop firstly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small projects ideas to teach beginners web developent using ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987057/small-projects-ideas-to-teach-beginners-web-developent-using-asp-net)

I am learning about technical skills to become a web developer.But i don't know how i should start to develop a web application.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/vcsharp/default.aspx

Comment: Can you let us know what you know already?

Answer (score 9):

The best application to develop first when learning a new technology is the good old ["Hello World!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) program.

The advantage of doing this is that you test that you have correctly installed and configured your technology stack without the extra confusion from possible bugs introduced in your code.

You could start with the most basic test: hardcoding "Hello World" in the page. Then try storing it in a variable and outputting it to the page dynamically. Then try reading it from an application configuration setting. Then try reading it from a database. Then reading a greeting from the user via a post and send it back to him.

This way you can test all the components of your stack and check that you understand how they work without taking on too much complexity at once.

Answer (score 1):

First get a hold of page life cycle and the basic controls of the web and their properties. If this is clear then every other thing follows and is easy to understand. Secondly there are numerous tutorials on msdn for all the controls and concepts of asp.net. Refer them.

Answer (score 1):

"w3 schools" is a great place to start to get an overview of the syntax for various languages. I really enjoy the screencasts at netuts.com when I'm looking to learn something new.

You're probably going to want to be confident tinkering with at least HTML, php, css and javascript before you try to take on clients or you'll just end up writing bad code and they'll be knocking on your door demanding a free fix when it inevitably breaks in 6 months' time.

There are certainly other languages that you can get into further down the track but that will cover your basic needs for encoding data, interacting with your server, making things look nice, and allowing your users to interact dynamically with your page.

You could also play with flash because it allows you to create very slick, dynamic elements relatively quickly and easily. IMO flash's relevance to the net as a whole (and getting paid work) is waning, so you can probably leave it on your "to-do" list, but that's definitly an opinion, not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

They are specifically asp.net and also a little dated as in .NET 2.0 but still relevant. Once you have a grasp of the fundamentals the [asp.net Data Access tutorials are a good place to look](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/)